# Getting this query to work?

Tags: mysql, count

Heya!, I have the below query:

```
SELECT t1.pm_id 
  FROM fb_user_pms AS t1, 
       fb_user_pm_replies AS t2 
 WHERE (t1.pm_id = '{$pm_id}' 
   AND t1.profile_author = '{$username}' 
    OR t1.pm_author = '{$username}' 
   AND t1.pm_id = t2.pm_id 
   AND t2.pm_author = '{$username}' 
   AND COUNT(t2.reply_id) > 0) 
   AND t1.deleted = 0
```

However, I'm getting a grouping error - my guess is its caused by the AND COUNT(t2.reply_id) > 0?

How can I rectify the above query to make it work.

Hope someone can help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you can't use an aggregate function (COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG, etc) in the WHERE clause, without it being inside a subquery.  Only the `HAVING` clause allows you to use aggregates without being wrapped in subqueries.

But checking for replies to be more than zero is not necessary on an INNER JOIN - that guarantees that there will be at least one reply associated to the `fb_user_pms` record.  The JOIN also means that the information in `t1` will be duplicated for every supported record in `fb_user_pm_replies`.  IE:  If a `fb_user_pms` record has three `fb_user_pm_replies` records related to it, you'll see the `fb_user_pms` record in the result set three times.

The query you want to use is:

```
SELECT t1.pm_id 
  FROM fb_user_pms AS t1 
 WHERE t1.pm_id = '{$pm_id}' 
   AND '{$username}' IN (t1.profile_author, t1.pm_author)
   AND t1.deleted = 0
   AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM fb_user_pm_replies AS t2 
               WHERE t2.pm_id = t1.pm_id
                 AND t2.pm_author = '{$username}')
```

The EXISTS clause returns true or false, based on the WHERE criteria.  It also won't duplicate `t1` results.

Comment: Ok great, what if I wanted to also select a column from t2. - how would I integrate that? e.g. SELECT t1.pm_id, t2.body FROM...

Comment: @Newbtophp: To get `t2` columns in the output, you have to use a JOIN.

Comment: Hmm yes but the bit which confuses me is i want to get the t2 only if it exists and im not sure how to do that?

Comment: @Newbtophp: If you want `fb_user_pms` records, and `fb_user_pm_replies` only if they exist to the parent--use `... FROM fb_user_pms a LEFT JOIN fb_user_pm_replies b ON b.pm_id = a.pm_id ...`.  Why is this not in your original question?

Answer (score 1):

The aggregate function `COUNT` can't go in the WHERE clause. You should use a GROUP BY and put it in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT t1.pm_id
FROM fb_user_pms AS t1
JOIN fb_user_pm_replies AS t2 ON t1.pm_id = t2.pm_id
WHERE (
         (t1.pm_id = '{$pm_id}' AND t1.profile_author = '{$username}') OR
         (t1.pm_author = '{$username}' AND t2.pm_author = '{$username}')
      ) AND t1.deleted = 0
GROUP BY t1.pm_id
HAVING COUNT(t2.reply_id) > 0
```

If `t2.reply_id` is a NOT NULL column then you don't need the HAVING clause at all.

Answer (score 0):

- The condition with COUNT must be in the HAVING part. It can not be part of the WHERE part.
- The SELECT part must be also use aggregate functions for example MAX(t1.pm_id)